# Word for "1 of 3"

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics

Is there a word (or two) for "N of M" form?

Example:

- "2nd" is an ordinal number
- "5 November 1605" is a date
- "3 of 5" is a ...?

Thanks!

Comment: "Fraction" i guess

Comment: _Ratio_ would also do depending on the context.

Comment: I always thought "3 of 5" was a Borg Drone...

Comment: Seeing how you yourself have provided an answer that doesn't match the question, I have to go with "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: *3 of 5* is an expression that equals 15. *3 OUT of 5* is a fraction equaling .6

Answer (score 1):

@TechieBee got me thinking.

Other candidates:

- Fraction
- Fragment
- Segment
- Slice
- Part
- Portion
- Division
- Portion

**Edit 1**

@mikeagg and @JHCL pointed out, *fraction* and *proportion* are good choices. Will pick one of those, I guess. Thank you folks!

**Edit 2**

All right, thanks everybody!

I'm using *fraction*. If anybody's wondering, here is the result of your help:

https://github.com/salutis/Progress-LocalizedFraction

P.S. I would love to accept somebody's answer but @RegDwigнt locked my question.

Comment: Fragment is not correct as it means "a small part broken off or separated from something"

Comment: Fraction and proportion are the the usual terms.

Comment: Oh..wow..you came up with so many!! happy to help :)

Comment: *Proportion* is a very good choice.

Comment: Most of these are horrible, awful, wrong or nonsensical choices. You might as well have listed *plumbing, SUV, daffodil*.

Comment: Both fraction and proportion are great. If anybody wants to answer this officially, I will accept the answer immediately. Thank you folks for helping me out!

Comment: It's not possible to answer while it's on hold. I would say "3 of 5" is a *permutation,* but the question is unclear because you have not specified how you are using "3 of 5"; it's certainly not the same as three-fifths.

Comment: @AndrewLeach You're right. It can represent three-fifts, e.g. you've completed 3 out of 5 things. But it can also represent 3 arbitrary elements in a collection of 5 elements.